# Firebase Firestore toObject fails on Boolean property mapping

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When pulling data from Firestore, I use `.toObject()` to map the data received into my data class, which is:

```
data class Img(var event_uid: String = "", var isVip: Boolean = false , var nombre: String = "", var url: String = "")
```

However, the mapping is not doing well. I received the field `isVip=>true` in the task, but the object field is mapped as false (default value).

[image: snapshot data]

[image: list of mapped object]

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I see in Logcat

```
W/Firestore: (0.6.6-dev) [zzevb]: No setter/field for isVip found on class ***.model.Img
```

According to [Kotlin Docu](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-to-kotlin-interop.html#properties):

> If the name of the property starts with is, a different name mapping
>   rule is used: the name of the getter will be the same as the property
>   name, and the name of the setter will be obtained by replacing is with
>   set. For example, for a property `isOpen`, the getter will be called
>   `isOpen()` and the setter will be called `setOpen()`. This rule applies
>   for properties of any type, not just `Boolean`.

Maybe a Firestore with Kotlin issue?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try adding `@field:JvmField` to `isValid` boolean property.

Comment: To solve my issue, I took your solution. However, the proper way should be handle as @Alex Mamo [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52294033/9697465).

Comment: How do you know about the `@field` attribute? It's not mentioned by the [`toObject`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#toObject(java.lang.Class<T>)) documentation. Could you point me to where one can read more about it? Maybe there are more useful attributes.

Comment: @t3chb0t `@field` is Kotlin annotation and it is not part of Firebase.  `@JvmField` annotation does the trick here, and it says to Kotlin compiler that it should not create getters and setters of isValid property and that it should expose this property as a field.

You can read more about `@field` and other annotation use site targets [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html?_ga=2.65505959.822283262.1593292835-1938789949.1575030406#annotation-use-site-targets).

Answer (score 9):

If you are using in your model class a field named `isVip` which is of type `Boolean`, when instantiating an object of your `Img` class using the following line of code:

```
val img = Img("Y9X ... zYn", true, "Nombre", "https://...")
```

The way in which your `isVip` property will look like in your database will be simply: `vip` and not `isVip` as you probably expected. The resason that your `isVip` property is stored as `isVip` and not just `vip` is because you didn't add your data in the database using your helper class but somehow manually.

The reason you have that warning is because you have in your database a field which has **no** correspondent in your model class. In your model class you have a field named `isVip` which should have in the database a correspondent field named `vip` and **not** `isVip`, as it is now. So Firestore cannot create a connection between those fields and that's why you have that warning.

To solve this, you can remove (if is possible) the old data from your database and add fresh data using your model class. You need to have the name of your property in your model class named `isVip` and in your database just only `vip`.

Or you can change the name of your property in your modelc class from `isVip` to simply `vip` and that's it.

Comment: Hello, your explanation is awesome, thanks for that. Make all sense. I added this fields when created the document in my Angular webapp and now using my Kotlin having this issue. I tried changing the property in Firestore and worked. However, I should change all my refenrences in my Angular app and that takes time, but probably is the correct solution. To solve my issue now, I took @TheTechWolf  [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52285505/9697465)