# Firestore document doesnt copy single value to my pojo class using (document.toObject(myPojo::class.java))

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, kotlin-android-extensions

Doument recieved from firestore contains a key as "isAccepted" which is of string datatype , but firestore function ( document.toObject(myModel::class.java)) does not copy this key to my pojo class , where as there are more string values which are being copied only the keys having "is" in the starting doesnt copy. In java it was working properly all values were copied.

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot, the content of your `myModel` class and the code that you are using to get data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Firestore toObject fails on Boolean property mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284861/firebase-firestore-toobject-fails-on-boolean-property-mapping)